# Boarding cards route finder

Tags: php, object-oriented

Recently I had an interview project, which I did and sent, so this question is not for avoiding thinking. I am just struggling to build my own opinion about it so I decided to ask in public.

My question in general is that: is the code design is too complex?

I know the opinions may vary, but in general: **do you PHP prefer the flat code and keeping the structures in just arrays, or is it better for you to spend twice a time but have something participated into small classes?**

The code is in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/filipgorny/Boarding).

The main class of this project is an API class. I call it the gateway point, or a package entry point. I was looking for existence of any pattern like that and could not find it, I mean the pattern of having a single class as a gateway point or rather an API for the whole package.

```
<?php

namespace Boarding;

use Boarding\Card\Factory\CardFactoryInterface;
use Boarding\Card\Stack;
use Boarding\Route\Descripting\RouteDescription;
use Boarding\Route\Descripting\RouteDescriptorInterface;
use Boarding\Route\PathFinding\PathFindingStrategyInterface;
use Boarding\Vehicle\Factory\VehicleFactoryInterface;

/**
 * Class Api
 * @package Boarding
 */
class Api
{
    /**
     * @var CardFactoryInterface
     */
    private $cardFactory;

    /**
     * @var PathFindingStrategyInterface
     */
    private $pathFindingStrategy;

    /**
     * @var RouteDescriptorInterface
     */
    private $descriptor;

    /**
     * @param CardFactoryInterface $cardFactory
     * @param PathFindingStrategyInterface $pathFindingStrategy
     * @param RouteDescriptorInterface $routeDescriptor
     */
    public function __construct(
        CardFactoryInterface $cardFactory,
        PathFindingStrategyInterface $pathFindingStrategy,
        RouteDescriptorInterface $routeDescriptor
    ) {
        $this->cardFactory = $cardFactory;
        $this->pathFindingStrategy = $pathFindingStrategy;
        $this->descriptor = $routeDescriptor;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new Stack object instance, using injected factory object
     *
     * @param $data
     * @return Stack
     */
    public function createStack($data)
    {
        $stack = new Stack();
        foreach ($data as $element) {
            $stack->addCard($this->cardFactory->createCard($element));
        }
        return $stack;
    }

    /**
     * @param Stack $stack
     * @return Route
     */
    public function findRoute(Stack $stack)
    {
        return $this->pathFindingStrategy->findPath($stack);
    }

    /**
     * @param Route $route
     * @return RouteDescription
     */
    public function describeRoute(Route $route)
    {
        return $this->descriptor->describeRoute($route);
    }
}
```

Example of the too complex point I am sensing is maybe the mapping from `Card` to `Leg`. The `Card` is an class representing user input data, and `Leg` the output, generated from the API. I am not sure if I should use separate class or maybe the same one as they are very similar in the structure, or maybe even they are identical. I do always separate classes like that to keep modifications easy but then the pragmatic approach tells me that this is too much and I am losing too much time thinking about where to put these basic things.

The `Card` class:

```
/**
 * Class Card
 * @package Boarding
 */
class Card
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $from;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $to;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $seat;

    /**
     * @var AbstractVehicle
     */
    private $vehicle;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $additionalInfo = [];

    /**
     * Card constructor.
     * @param string $from
     * @param string $to
     * @param string $seat
     * @param AbstractVehicle $vehicle
     */
    public function __construct($from = null, $to = null, $seat = null, AbstractVehicle $vehicle = null)
    {
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->seat = $seat;
        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFrom()
    {
        return $this->from;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $from
     */
    public function setFrom($from)
    {
        $this->from = $from;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTo()
    {
        return $this->to;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $to
     */
    public function setTo($to)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSeat()
    {
        return $this->seat;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $seat
     */
    public function setSeat($seat)
    {
        $this->seat = $seat;
    }

    /**
     * @return AbstractVehicle
     */
    public function getVehicle()
    {
        return $this->vehicle;
    }

    /**
     * @param AbstractVehicle $vehicle
     */
    public function setVehicle($vehicle)
    {
        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getAdditionalInfo($name)
    {
        return isset($this->additionalInfo[$name]) ? $this->additionalInfo[$name] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setAdditionalInfo($name, $value)
    {
        $this->additionalInfo[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return \string[]
     */
    public function getAllAdditionalInfo()
    {
        return $this->additionalInfo;
    }
}
```